# I want to make all the Hebrew letters

Tags: hebrew

I would like to make all the Hebrew letters without loading up my preamble.

I looked at this post but I didn't see if all the letters could be made.

As of right now, the main letter i want is `waw`

[What are TeX codes for Hebrew letters to be used as math-mode symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226793/what-are-tex-codes-for-hebrew-letters-to-be-used-as-math-mode-symbols)

Comment: If you know how to display Hebrew letters in text mode, define `\newcommand\mathvav{\textup{ו}}`.

Comment: There are also some mathematical Hebrew letter-like symbols defined in Unicode that you can use with `univode-math`.

Comment: After looking for the shape of waw and checking in the table in my answer to the question you linked, I guess that waw is at slot `"4E`, so you can do `\DeclareMathSymbol{\waw}{\mathord}{hebrewletters}{"4E}`

Comment: Added an updated answer to [the earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226793/what-are-tex-codes-for-hebrew-letters-to-be-used-as-math-mode-symbols), which we might want to redirect this one to?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample that works in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  I use Libertinus as an example of a font that contains Hebrew letters, but you can use any font that does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus} % For example

\newcommand\mathvav{\textup{\symbol{"05D5}}} % ו

\begin{document}
\section*{The Symbol \(\mathvav\)}

\( f(t) \cdot \mathvav \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus sample]

You can use any text-mode command within the `\textup` or `\textnormal` commands from `amsmath` (which `libertinus` loads indirectly), including changing to a Hebrew font.

Comment: Libertinus.sty Where do I find this? I'm using Overleaf.com

Comment: It should be `\usepackage{libertinus}` (with lower case L).

Comment: @JasperHabicht Whoops, typo might have broken the MWE on a different OS. Thanks!